# Some doubts about Hadoop DFS and MapReduce

Tags: database, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

1. HDFS stores data in blocks of 64MB/128MB and the data is replicated across task nodes in these block sizes. This blocks are stored in nodes' Hard-disks. Correct me if I am wrong in this statement.
2. Is this block loaded completely into the RAM or does it need to be streamed line by line? Or both are possible?
3. Lets say I have a 1GB CSV file on which I want to perform some computations which are not independent for each row in that CSV file. I mean that the computations require to process 10 consecutive rows. For eg:  computation on rows 1:10, then on 2:11, then 3:12 and so on.. What are my options? Is it a good idea to convert this 1 GB multi-row data into a single line data and then loading it as one single matrix (I guess this will overflow the RAM if computations are complex to compute on whole 64MB/128MB block)?

Answer (score 0):

1) The data is replicated along datanodes. In most configurations you want your tasknodes be also datanodes. And yes, it is stored physically.

2) Hadoop user something like bufferedreaders on the input split and "streams" the data line by line if you use the standard reader. there are other readers as well and you could also implement your own reader

3) If you want to process 10 rows of a file there are several ways to do so. One would be to set your file to nonsplitable. Then it is guaranteed that the whole CSV is processed by one mapper. you may split the file by yourself to let a lot mapper work. other approaches I can think of are far more complicated or have problems at block borders. I think it is not the best idea to load the whole file, when your .csv becomes bigger in future your approach has to fail.

if your job is a map only job, you can add a reduce phase and calculate a spcial key for those 10 rows (e.g. they are related to a special issue and so on) and get all lines related in your reducer. unfortunately i didn't know enough about your job to be more specific

if you are new to hadoop, that [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/) might help you to get into it

Answer (score 0):

1) You are correct (and block sizes are configurable but I will just briefly go over the Hadoop architecture. Hadoop has a master/slave architecture with two daemon groups: NameNode/DataNode/SecondaryNameNode (SNN) and JobTracker/TaskTracker. The NameNode is responsible for keeping track of how the data files are broken down into file blocks and which datanodes they reside in. NameNodes dont usually double as DataNodes. The DataNodes read and write HDFS blocks to the local file system (disk) and communicates with other DataNodes for replication. The SNN is an assistant daemon which communicates with the NameNode and serves to minimize the downtime and loss of data incase the single-point-of-failure NameNode goes down. The JobTracker master determines the execution plan of your code and the TaskTracker slaves execute the individual tasks that the JobTracker assigns.

2) The NameNode keeps track of all the datanode namespaces in RAM. Once the data is loaded into HDFS, it is streamed from disk for processing (HDFS is optimized for sequential data access) The streaming is only limited by the maximum I/O rate of the drives the data is stored on. Please see this Cloudera post for optimal HDFS block sizes http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

3) Can you describe your use case a bit more? You may have to define your own InputSplits which can be fairly involved (see: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html). If you have control over your dataset you can preprocess it. Or if you can control your file sizes you can write your files out in chunks of lets say 62MB for block sizes of 64MB.

Comment: Would splitting a big file into sizes of around ~60MB gurantee that the each single data block contains one ~60MB file?

Comment: I haven't tried that approach myself but based on how HDFS works it should be possible and worth experimenting with.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 3):

if you don't mind the loss of a handful of your 10 line sets, a very simple and fast solution isto build a bit of code around a [LineReader](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/LineReader.html) - the first time the mapper asks for a key/value pair, your version of the LineReader reads 10 lines and for all subsequent calls, you read line by line. This requires just a few lines of extra code.